# I did an 'imports' - error TYPE EXPECTED

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf, itext

I did this:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.rtf
```

and then this:

```
Dim grx As graphic = New graphic
```

and on the first "graphic" I am getting a "type expected"

graphic is a member of iTextSharp.text.rtf

Here's the surrounding code:

```
Public Sub New1()
    Console.WriteLine("Chapter 4 example 4: Simple Graphic")
    Dim document As Document = New Document
    Try
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream("Chap0404.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        document.Open()
        Dim grx As graphic = New graphic
        grx.Rectangle(100, 700, 100, 100)
        grx.MoveTo(100, 700)
        grx.LineTo(200, 800)
        grx.Stroke()
        document.Add(grx)
    Catch de As DocumentException
        Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message)
    Catch ioe As IOException
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message)
    End Try
    document.Close()
End Sub
```

Here's the entire tutorial: (sorry its not a tutorial but thats what they call it)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Namespace iTextSharp.tutorial.Chap04

Public Class Chap0404

    Public Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("Chapter 4 example 4: Simple Graphic")
        Dim document As Document = New Document
        Try
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream("Chap0404.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            document.Open
            Dim grx As Graphic = New Graphic
            grx.Rectangle(100, 700, 100, 100)
            grx.MoveTo(100, 700)
            grx.LineTo(200, 800)
            grx.Stroke
            document.Add(grx)
        Catch de As DocumentException
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message)
        Catch ioe As IOException
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message)
        End Try
        document.Close
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: Could you please post the surrounding source? Often this type of error is caused by code close to the specified line, not exactly on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with this for a while I think the conclusion is that the tutorial you're following applies to an out-of-date version of iText / iTextSharp.

Their [sourceforge](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) site links to a matching [example](http://blog.rubypdf.com/itextsharp/tutorial01/ap04Chap0404.cs.html) from January of 2006, and your translation to VB.NET looks accurate--the problem is that the current version of iTextSharp doesn't contain a `Graphic` type, and after some searching it doesn't appear to have been *just* renamed--it's more likely that the full graphics API has been significantly altered.

The sourceforge page has a disclaimer (last line) that the linked examples might not work anymore,

> Note that some of the example won't work with the most recent version of iTextSharp.

With the given evidence, and the use of Reflector, I found that the expected `Graphic.Stroke()` method only exists within the `PdfContentByte` class; however `Document.Add()` expects a class that implements `IElement`, which `PdfContentByte` doesn't do.

That change is the smallest I could make to get ***close*** to compiling, but it significantly alters the intent of the code and probably won't function as expected.  Here's my updated version for your reference though:

```
Public Class Chap0404

    Public Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("Chapter 4 example 4: Simple Graphic")
        Dim document As Document = New Document
        Try
            Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream("Chap0404.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            document.Open()
            Dim grx As PdfContentByte = New PdfContentByte(writer)
            grx.Rectangle(100, 700, 100, 100)
            grx.MoveTo(100, 700)
            grx.LineTo(200, 800)
            grx.Stroke()
            'document.Add(grx)
        Catch de As DocumentException
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message)
        Catch ioe As IOException
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message)
        End Try
        document.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does the Imports statement look correct in VS (no squiggley?); are you sure you've got all necessary references?

Comment: ...you're gonna make me go download the library then... so be it!  :-)

Comment: updated the answer, but it's still not what you're after.  What's the URL of the tutorial you're looking at?