# WidthPercentage not a member of itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf

for this line:

```
 c.WidthPercentage = 100F
```

i am getting this error:

Error   1   'WidthPercentage' is not a member of 'iTextSharp.text.Table'.

here's the entire code. it's taken directly from the tutorial

Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Namespace iTextSharp.tutorial.Chap05

```
Public Class Chap0514

    Public Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("Chapter 5 example 14: nested tables")
        Dim document As Document = New Document
        Try
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream("Chap0514.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            document.Open
            Dim secondTable As Table = New Table(2)
            secondTable.AddCell("2nd table 0.0")
            secondTable.AddCell("2nd table 0.1")
            secondTable.AddCell("2nd table 1.0")
            secondTable.AddCell("2nd table 1.1")
            Dim aTable As Table = New Table(4, 4)
            aTable.AutoFillEmptyCells = True
            aTable.AddCell("2.2", New Point(2, 2))
            aTable.AddCell("3.3", New Point(3, 3))
            aTable.AddCell("2.1", New Point(2, 1))
            aTable.InsertTable(secondTable, New Point(1, 3))
            document.Add(aTable)
            Dim thirdTable As Table = New Table(2)
            thirdTable.AddCell("3rd table 0.0")
            thirdTable.AddCell("3rd table 0.1")
            thirdTable.AddCell("3rd table 1.0")
            thirdTable.AddCell("3rd table 1.1")
            aTable = New Table(5, 5)
            aTable.AutoFillEmptyCells = True
            aTable.AddCell("2.2", New Point(2, 2))
            aTable.AddCell("3.3", New Point(3, 3))
            aTable.AddCell("2.1", New Point(2, 1))
            aTable.InsertTable(secondTable, New Point(1, 3))
            aTable.InsertTable(thirdTable, New Point(6, 2))
            document.Add(aTable)
            Dim a As Table = New Table(2)
            a.Widths = New Single() {85, 15}
            a.AddCell("a-1")
            a.AddCell("a-2")
            Dim b As Table = New Table(5)
            b.Widths = New Single() {15, 7, 7, 7, 7}
            b.AddCell("b-1")
            b.AddCell("b-2")
            b.AddCell("b-3")
            b.AddCell("b-4")
            b.AddCell("b-5")
            Dim c As Table = New Table(3, 1)
            c.WidthPercentage = 100F
            c.Widths = New Single() {20, 2, 78}
            c.InsertTable(a, New Point(0, 0))
            c.InsertTable(b, New Point(0, 2))
            document.Add(c)
            Dim t1 As Table = New Table(3)
            t1.AddCell("1.1")
            t1.AddCell("1.2")
            t1.AddCell("1.3")
            Dim t2 As Table = New Table(2)
            t2.AddCell("2.1")
            t2.AddCell("2.2")
            t1.InsertTable(t2)
            t1.AddCell("new cell")
            document.Add(t1)
            t1 = New Table(2, 2)
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            While i < 4
                t1.AddCell("t1")
                System.Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i),i-1)
            End While
            t2 = New Table(3, 3)
            i= 0
            While i < 9
                If i = 4 Then
                    t2.InsertTable(t1)
                Else
                    t2.AddCell("t2")
                End If
                System.Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i),i-1)
            End While
            Dim t3 As Table = New Table(4, 4)
            i= 0
            While i < 16
                If i = 10 Then
                    t3.InsertTable(t2)
                Else
                    t3.AddCell("t3")
                End If
                System.Math.Min(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i),i-1)
            End While
            document.Add(t3)
        Catch de As DocumentException
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message)
        Catch ioe As IOException
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message)
        End Try
        document.Close
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are using a version of iTextSharp that is more recent than the version used in the tutorial.  This should work:

```
c.Width = 100F
```

Comment: perhaps you can answer this question as well?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331253/i-did-an-imports-error-type-expected

Comment: also can i please please have your contact info, i want to ask you more questions on itextsharp

Comment: Why not let everyone see the questions? That's what SO is for.